# content is exceeding my box (small CSS issue)

Tags: css, flexbox

Im copying this Gensis Theme for CSS practice: http://my.studiopress.com/themes/daily-dish/#demo-full

I am now having an issue, since one of the black boxes exceeds its parent-Box.
The attribute causing this is the following code

```
.heading{
    padding-left: 2em;
```

however I want this padding. How do I make the black background stop at the end  of the parent box(id='right_1') and maintain the left padding?
*You have to scroll to the right when you run the snippet to see the issue

```css
*{
    margin: 0 auto;
}

body{
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-image: url('background.png');
}


.heading{
    padding-left: 2em;
    border: 1px solid green;
    font-size: 1em;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    height: 40px;
}


header{
    padding: 70px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

#wrapper{
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 960px;
    height: 2000px;
    background: white;
}

main{
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.blackbox{
    
}
#left {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    height: 1000px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#left_1{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}

#right {
    margin-left: 5%;
    width: 30%;
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#right_1{  
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<main>
 <section id='left'>
  <section id='left_1'>
   <h2 class='heading'>Featured Dish</h2>
  </section>
 </section>

 <aside id='right'>
  <aside id='right_1'>
   <h2 class='heading'>About the Author</h2>
  </aside>
 </aside>
</main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `box-sizing:border-box` to the `.heading` element.

This way the width and height properties include the padding.

CSS would be:

```
.heading {
   padding-left: 2em;
   border: 1px solid green;
   font-size: 1em;
   display: flex;
   width: 100%;
   align-items: center;
   color: white;
   background-color: black;
   height: 40px;
   box-sizing: border-box; // Add box-sizing: border-box
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   }
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this issue making `box-sizing: border-box;`

Try below CSS

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/shanidkv/omn6k0yu/1/)**

**[Read more about box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)**

Comment: thank you! But already got the answer, you guys are so quick, love it :)